# error C2039: 'ClientSpottingTargetComponent' : is not a member of 'fb'

Tags: components

Hi can any one tell me how to solve this problem ?

here is my code

```
#ifndef _GetComponentFunction_H
#define _GetComponentFunction_H
namespace fb
{
//Minimap
fb::ClientSpottingTargetComponent *cstc = soldier->getComponent<fb::ClientSpottingTargetComponent>( "ClientSpottingTargetComponent" );
        cstc->m_spotType = fb::SpotType_Active;

#endif
```

Comment: what language is this? please tag it as such...I assume C/C++ ?

Comment: What is your problem? What are you trying to do? What doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is a header file defining `ClientSpottingTargetComponent` that you need to include.

Be aware you might need to add relevant source files too, or link against a relevant library.

Comment: do i need to include it ?

Comment: Yes. #include [header file name]

Comment: i now get this error C2059: syntax error : 'constant' here is the location  PAD(0x18);     it is on the ClientSpottingTargetComponent

Comment: That's a new question